# Can the text message field in iOS 10 Messages be moved to be more friendly to left-handed users?

Tags: messages, ios

I have noticed that with iOS 10 Messages that the text message field is in a very inconvenient place for left-handed users.

[image: iOS 10 Messages left handed woes]

As you can see, the lesser-used photo, gestures, and store button are in easy reach of the left-handed user's dominant thumb while the frequently-used text message field is far away from it. The inverse is true for right-handed users.

Is there any way to changed this so that the text message field is under a left-handed user's thumb? Perhaps as an accessibility option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no documentation from Apple that indicates whether or not the buttons in Messages can be moved to the opposite site.  This is actually a good opportunity for the app development or jailbreak tweaking community.

I would recommend [contacting Apple](http://www.apple.com/feedback/) and giving them your feedback.